# Resolve merge conflicts toolbar not showing in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm using the latest version of VS Code, and did a `git stash`, `git pull`, `git stash apply`. Normally when there are merge conflicts I can see [this toolbar](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tips-and-tricks#resolve-merge-conflicts) to solve them (`Accept incoming`, etc.) but this time the toolbar was not there. Is this a bug, or just a feature that now needs to be enabled manually?

Screenshot
[image]

```
Version: 1.42.1
Commit: c47d83b293181d9be64f27ff093689e8e7aed054
Date: 2020-02-11T14:44:27.652Z
Electron: 6.1.6
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable the code Lens parameter in the vs code settings Under section editor différence

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to my vscode; the solution for me was to open settings (command+comma), search for merge, and disable Git: Merge Editor.

Reload vscode (ctr + R)

Thanks to [Abe Dolinger](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157325#issuecomment-1206849212)