# Merge Conflict is not showing up on VS Code

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict, merge-conflict

I am starting to learn Git. I'm watching a video and learning from it. Right now I'm learning merge conflicts. I have a file in my GitHub repository and I have the same HTML file downloaded onto my laptop. To simulate a merge conflict, I edited  on my local file (I added an extra !) and my GitHub file (I added an inline style).

[HTML file on my laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRcXy.png)

[GitHub HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhKQn.png)

I did the git pull command on my terminal and it says "You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them".

[My terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDSY9.png)

When I go back to my code in my laptop, I don't see the conflict markers the way the professor sees it in his file.

[Professor's screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fThhj.png)

I don't know why this is happening. I googled it but I can't find an answer. I tried following the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73550489/20316015) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549224/resolve-merge-conflicts-toolbar-not-showing-in-vs-code), but it still doesn't work.

What do I do?

Comment: I'm guessing that the professor had already configured his git to handle this situation, and either he didn't explain that, or you overlooked it.

Comment: Or the guide is for an older git version with different default behavior.